# Pythonic way to classify a value to bin

Tags: python, classification, numeric, bins

I've went through multiple excamples of data classification however either I didn't get it or those are not applicable in my case.

I have a list of values:

```
values = [-130,-110,-90,-80,-60,-40]
```

All I need to do is to classify `input` integer value to appropriate "bin".

E.g., `input=-97` should get `index 1` (between -110, to -90) , while `input=-140` should get 0.

I don't want to do it `if...elif else style` since values could be dynamic.

What would be the most pythonic way to do it? I guess no pandas/numpy is necessary

Regards

Comment: Do all "bins" have the same width? Are they consecutive? Are the input values always integers, or can they be arbitrary floats?

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the list of bins and find the index of the **first** (`[0]`) bin boundary that is bigger than the classified value. Then step back to the previous bin number:

```
val = -97
[i for i,p in enumerate(values) if p > val][0] - 1
# 1
```

This solution works only for `values[0] <= val < values[-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with embedded module - `bisect`.

`bisect_left(a, x)` return the index to insert into the list `a` to the left of values greater `x` than the input. Check index into sotrted list.

If my interpretation of your question is right code like this.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
values = [-130,-110,-90,-80,-60,-40]

i = bisect_left(values, -97)
if i > 0:
    i -= 1
```